# Reference to type '(, )' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this compile time error in my wpf project suddenly in VS 2019, which was working fine till now.

**Error:Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7069  Reference to type '(, )' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found**

Same project if i run in VS 2017 it works fine, i tried many things like clearing temp files, re clone my code base but nothing helped me. I do not get which type it is claiming from the error as '(,)'.

Could someone please assist me what is this issue and why am i getting only in VS2019 and not in VS2017 and any way to resolve this. I have spent lots of my time already any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that error point to some specific code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Reference to type claims it is defined, but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469385/error-reference-to-type-claims-it-is-defined-but-it-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @DCCoder no, this page i have already visited and does not solve  my problem. 
Do you have any idea what "Reference to type '(, )' " in the error means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error CS7069 Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374921/error-cs7069-reference-to-type-image-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-drawing)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to AngryHacker's suggestion, make sure that if you have multiple projects, that their .NET versions all match up.

In my case, I had a project built with .NET Framework 4.7.2 where I defined a method that returned a ValueTuple and then I called that method from another project built with .NET Framework 4.6.1.  After upgrading the project's .NET version from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 and relaunching VisualStudio, I was able to build the code.

Comment: Ì had this 4.6 set for my project. 4.6.2 worked for me. Just in case if anyone had similar issue. Thanks @Sean Killian

Answer (score 3):

Install `System.ValueTuple` package into your project.  That's what is likely causing errors for you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this in VS2019 when you were not in VS2017 is that a newer version of `System.ValueTuple` is being included in your project during the build.

You can find where this is by building with diagnostic logging and looking for System.ValueTuple in the logs. I had this issue and found this:

> `Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ValueTuple.dll"`

With your build logs you should be able to find where to fix it in your project but as @angryhacker mentioned in his answer one way is to specifically include the `System.ValueTuple` that your projects expect in the references of your project, or to install the Nuget package in your project.

@sean-killian describes another way that the versions can disagree. The compile error is cryptic, but you should find that on the line of code referenced the `System.ValueTuple` type is being used in your code, or in the signature of the function that you are calling.