# Error CS7069 Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, uwp, imageprocessor, system.drawing.color

I had the original Problem that System.Drawing does not work in UWP applications. after a short web search ImageProcessor (https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/#about) showed up.
My current situation is:

I am trying to change a white image to an certain color, now it seams that ImageProcessor uses System.Drawing.Color but that makes no problem. What does make a problem is that if i address an object of ImageFactory it responds with this error Message: CS7069 Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found.

Here is my Code:

```
byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(source);

                        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
                                {
                                    imageFactory.Load(inStream).BackgroundColor(Color.FromArgb(argb[0],argb[1],argb[2], argb[3])).Save(outStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

The red line is under imageFactory.Load.

If you know how to fix this or if you know hoe to do it different that would be cool. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to install ImageProcessor in a uwp app and I got the following warning:

```
ImageProcessor 2.9.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 'UAP,Version=v10.0.17763'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Made a .net Core console app - same warning.

It appears that ImageProcessor requires a .Net target framework.

In-fact I have made a simple .net 4.7 console app and this is the result:

[image]

On inspection of the nuget packages it clearly states the dependency:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i am a little embarrased that i missed the verry obvious

Comment: No worries - it happens to all of us  - to miss stuff from time to time.